# Remove files from directory that do not have corresponding pair in another directory based on file prefix?

Tags: files, find

I have two directories, dir1 and dir2 and I want to remove files in dir2 that do not have a corresponding pair in dir1.  The pair is defined by the first three fields of the filename prefix separated by an underscore.  For example:

dir1 contains:

```
U006_S2_pr_hrrre_1760-1790_fil.csv
U006_S2_ta_hrrre_1760-1790_fil.csv
```

dir2 contains:

```
U006_S2_ep_prc4_1660-1790_fil.csv
U006_S2_ep_prc8_1760-1899_fil.csv
U006_S2_pr_prc8_1260-1090_fil.csv
U006_S2_ta_prc4_1860-2790_fil.csv
```

I would want to get rid of

```
U006_S2_ep_prc4_1660-1790_fil.csv 
U006_S2_ep_prc8_1760-1899_fil.csv
```

but keep the remaining files. There are thousands of files in each directory.  All files in dir1 have a corresponding pair in dir2, but dir2 has many extra files without corresponding pairs in dir1.